# homebrew show all pinned formulas

Tags: homebrew

Homebrew has command, which tells it to stop upgrading mentioned formulas:

`$ brew pin $FORMULA`

Does anyone know if there is any homebrew command which shows the list of pinned formulas?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`brew list --pinned` should do the trick.

I'm using brew version 0.9.5. The solution is listed in the manual pages as follows:

> ls, list [--unbrewed] [--versions [--multiple]] [--pinned] [formulae]
>     Without any arguments, list all installed formulae.
>
> If  formulae are given, list the installed files for formulae.
>   Combined with     --verbose, recursively list the contents of all
>   subdirectories in each  for-  mula's keg.
>
> If --unbrewed is passed, list all files in the Homebrew prefix not
>   installed     by Homebrew.
>
> If --versions is passed, show the version number for installed
>   formulae,  or     only  the  specified  formulae  if formulae are given.
>   With --multiple, only     show formulae with multiple versions installed.
>
> If --pinned is passed, show the versions of pinned  formulae,  or 
>   only  the     specified (pinned) formulae if formulae are given. See also
>   pin, unpin.